# How to remove a number from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, let

I am trying to use an array in my code but I am getting an error message that says pop is not defined. I want to remove the number 50 from the array.

Here is what I tried:

```js
let digits = [5,25,50,100]
let allDigits = digits
allDigits[pop](50)
```

Comment: well, no, you haven't defined `pop` variable you are using ... did you mean `.pop` instead? note: `pop` method does not take an argument - you can supply one, but it's ignored

Comment: `pop` only removes the last element from the array. What you want might be [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): `let allDigits = digits.filter(digit => digit !== 50)`.

Comment: You use methods with dot notation (`allDigits.pop()`), not square brackets.

Comment: Are you sure you're working in [tag:javascript]?

Comment: If you really want to _remove_ the value from the array `digits.splice(digits.indexOf(50), 1)`